# Angular:8 Export Excel consider numbers data type as text

Tags: excel, typescript, angular8, export-to-excel, xlsx

I have a requirement where in need to download a template with columns names and need to format the data type for some columns as text even numbers are entered. i'm using the angular's SheetJS js-xlsx to export the excel.

```
var jsonData = [];
jsonData.push({ "Product Name": "\0", "Barcode": "\0", "Serial Number": "\0", "Grid Number": "\0" });
this.exportExcel(jsonData, "ProductTemplate.xlsx")
---------------------------------------------
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
  public exportExcel(jsonData: any[],fileName?: any): void {
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    this.saveExcelFile(excelBuffer,fileName);
  }

  private saveExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName?: any): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: this.fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName);
  }
```

Here i have 10digit barcode, serialnumbers, the problem is i want them to display as it is ex: if user enters 0001234567 as barcode the 0's are getting deleted since it is treated as number, if i can make those columns(B,C)'s data type as text while downloading the template itself then if user enters 0's it'll stay as it is in Excel. i tried adding \0 which treats as string,but still not working.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jonasrenault/setting-up-pagination-with-angularjs-and-django-rest-framework-4acadd4b787a